# Opening a menu item using iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

When I click on a menu item is it possible to open the link from the iframe? I have some knowledge of php.

```
        </tr>
        <tr align="left" height="25" bgcolor="#B3BBB5">
            <td class="textmenu">

                <a href="Home.php">Home</a> |
                <a href="Aboutus.php">About Us</a> |
                <a href="contactinfo.php">Contact Us</a>  
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr align="center">
            <td width="100%"><div style="height:510px;">
                <iframe src="Home.php" width="100%" name="scs_body" frameborder="no" style="height:500px;" ></iframe> 
            </div></td>
```

Comment: Yes, its possible, but such a bad idea i wont tell you how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. **But please don't do it.** It's very outdated and bad design IMO.

*Target* your `<iframe>` name on the anchors you want to load:

```
<a href="Home.php" target="scs_body">Home</a>
```